# angular.js agnostic filter

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am new in Angular.js, I am reading my first book and thought to stop and experiment with what I've learned so far. I try to create a `limitTo` filter , but the number will be inserted by the user.

```
        <script>
            var monthly=[123.659855, 89.645222, 97.235644, 129.555555]
            function MyFilterDemoCtrl($scope) {$scope.monthly= monthly;};
        </script>

 Num: <input ng-model="num" type="text" />

         <li ng-controller="MyFilterDemoCtrl" ng-repeat="gigabytes in monthly | limitTo:{{num}}"> {{ gigabytes | number:2}} </li>
```

So when I type `3` in the `Num` only the first three numbers are printed in the `li`. But I get nothing. What am I missing and what is the proper way to implement such task? Should I code like `limitTo:{{num}}` or `limitTo:num`

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: How to change ng-repeat limitTo based on variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984727/angularjs-how-to-change-ng-repeat-limitto-based-on-variable)

Comment: Lots of questions: (1) Where is the rest of the code? I see the controller function, but I don't see that it is tied to a module. (2) You set the controller at the <li> element, but the num property is bound outside of that... is there a parent controller which owns the num property? (3) What does the limitTo filter do? Where is you filter definition for it? ---- And a change: (3) Change limitTo: {{num}} to just limitTo:num.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need to have the `ng-model="num"` in the controller's scope. Simply moving the `ng-controller` outside its declaration fixes this.
2. It should be `limitTo: num` rather than `limitTo: {{num}}`. You are not interpolating the value of num into a string.

```js
var monthly = [123.659855, 89.645222, 97.235644, 129.555555];

function MyFilterDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.monthly = monthly;
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyFilterDemoCtrl', MyFilterDemoCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyFilterDemoCtrl">  
  
  Num: <input ng-model="num" type="text" />

  <li ng-repeat="gigabytes in monthly | limitTo: num"> 
      {{ gigabytes | number:2}} 
  </li>
         
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that was awesome

Comment: Glad to help. If that sorts you out can you mark my answer as the solution.

Comment: I had some extra questions. If you like, check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31711092/angular-js-filter-has-dynamic-and-default-value`