# How to show the most recent messages?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My task is actually trying to make a broadcast messages to show the most recent messages in a limited number only. I have found how to limit the messages in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984727/angularjs-how-to-change-ng-repeat-limitto-based-on-variable). But right now i am struggling on how to show only the latest messages. I'm new in this angular, hope you can explain it in a simple way please. Thank you.

If there's 10 messages:

```
message 1
message 2
message 3
message 4
message 5
message 6
message 7
message 8
message 9
message 10
```

There result should be:

```
message 6
message 7
message 8
message 9
message 10
```

Here is the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="score in scores | limitTo: limit">
..........
</div>
```

In controller:

```
var limitStep = 5;
$scope.limit = limitStep;
$scope.incrementLimit = function() {
    $scope.limit += limitStep;
};
$scope.decrementLimit = function() {
    $scope.limit -= limitStep;
};
```

Comment: Why don't you broadcast new message in top? Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/DieuNQ/xvL1pnkL/), I think it is an easy solution for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `limitTo: -limit`, `-` helps to select from the last.

```
<div ng-repeat="score in scores | limitTo: -limit">
```

[LimitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo):

> Creates a new array or string containing only a specified number of elements. The elements are taken from either the beginning or the end of the source array, string or number, as specified by the value and sign (positive or negative) of limit.

Comment: very simple and effective. Hahahahaha. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by slicing the values,

```
 <ul ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal.slice(5, 10)">
    <li>{{strVal}}</li>
  </ul>
```

Or by using angular Feature [`LimitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

```
<div ng-repeat="strVal in arrVal| limitTo: 10 | limitTo: -5">{{strVal }}</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3mystte4/1/)