# Angular js ng-repeat hanging the browser for more than 10000 records

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat in the options tag while displaying a select box. When my records reach 10000 my browser hangs...I have used :: to disable bijection. I want to use limitTo but am unable to change it dynamically when the user scrolls down. Can someone please tell me a way to handle this issue.

If required I can use an auto complete box also.....Can anyone suggest how to use an autocomplete box with angular js

I finally used HTML5 datalist binding it with angular js ng-repeat......it is working now......

Comment: Don't render 10000 entries, or any number even close to that.  Use lazy loading instead.

Comment: I need to use the dropdown..can you tell me how to do this using the dropdown

Comment: Do you really have 10,000 options in a dropdown? Is it an option to create a search select box and limit the result list?

Comment: No...that is not a option as of now

Comment: So, you expect the user to scroll through thousands of options?

Comment: yes.................do you have an answer to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use **limitTo** filter, which will limit the dataset that needs to be displayed on the view,

```
<div ng-repeat="datobj in data | limitTo:1000">{{datobj}}</div>
```

Comment: But what should I do when I want to display the next 1000 records...without the user having to click a button to view the next 1000 records

Comment: you can write a function and pass the value on ng click

Comment: on the scroll bar only :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984727/angularjs-how-to-change-ng-repeat-limitto-based-on-variable

Comment: how do I capture click even on scroll bar by select

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132486/discussion-between-prashant-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <ul ng-show="search.length>3">
      <li ng-click="selectObject(obj)" ng-repeat="obj in objList| filter:search">
   </ul>
```

This will show the drop-down when user has typed in more than 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<select class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select" data-ng-model="modelValue" data-ng-change="ChangeModel(modelValue)" ng-options="la.Value as la.Key for la in object"> </select>

   $scope.ChangeModel = function (value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.modelValue = $scope.modelValue.replace(/string:/g, "");
            if (!$scope.$root.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        })
    }
```